# Выводить значение по алфавиту

Tags: php, mysql

Берем из базы имена с фамилиями и как можно их вывести на алфавиту?

Comment: И что не получается? Хоспади, ну <a href="http://www.google.ru/search?q=MySql по алфавиту">гуглом-то</a> можно сперва воспользоваться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По какому полю нужно сортировать?
Можно так:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `name` ASC - по возрастанию имени
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `name` DESC - по убыванию имени
```

Тоже самое для поля фамилии

Answer (score 0):

Ну если ORDER by `id` выводит строки id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc... то, видимо, ORDER by `name`.